# Could not login with bash shell by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I want to run a Ruby on Rails application. When I tried to run it, it shows me this,

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby-railties
```

So, I figured out the problem and I found that the problem is due to not login into bash shell. My terminal could not execute 'ruby' or 'ruby on rails' scripts. I checked .bashrc and .bash_profile files if PATH variable is set to point to rvm file.
When I did,

```
/bash/bin -l
```

it shows me ruby or rails are installed on system and I could start Rails server successfully. But if I opened another Terminal window, same problem occurs. Basically, I want to log into bash shell by default. Please correct and help me to sort out this. Thanks!

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Linux? macOS?
Did you mean /bin/bash ?
Your terminal program probably has profiles, which can be configured to open a login shell by default.

Comment: Use the `chsh` command to change your login shell.

Comment: Which shell do you login to then?  There are several ways to find out, the simplest is to login then use `ps` (no parameters) - that will show the name of the shell program.

Comment: Try: `bundle exec rails` (if you are using bundler, and you probably are)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the location of your bash shell is **/bin/bash** you could use this command (replacing "username" with your username):

```
chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

That will change your default shell in most unix like operating systems.
Afterwards you can verify it checking /etc/passwd where you will see the default shell at the end of the line of your username.

**Warning**: *Try it first with a new user, in order to avoid losing your shell access if the path to bash is different :-)*

Comment: I discovered that I was logged in bash shell by default. But when I do, /bin/bash --login, it actually reads environment variables from .bash_profile file. In my case,
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" is written in .bash_profile file. I just added this line in .bashrc file at the end and the problem is solved for me. I referred this [AskUbuntu] thread (http://askubuntu.com/questions/444880/why-do-i-need-to-run-bin-bash-login)